# Java try-catch not catching exception

Tags: java, exception, selenium, try-catch

I have the following method:

```
private void checkIfLoggedIn() {
  try{
    try {
      new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
             By.cssSelector("a[href*='score']")));
    } 
    catch (WebDriverException e) {
    } 
    loggedInState = 2;
  }
  catch (TimeoutException e) {
    loggedInState = -1;
  }
}
```

Simply put, this method's job is to wait until the webpage finishes loading the logged-in pa
ge, and let the rest of the code know by changing a variable. This code works perfectly the vast majority of the time, however if the driver is closed (by another thread) before it finishes, it crashes. I'm perfectly fine with the code stopping - If the webpage has closed it has most likely finished it's task (or crashed for a different reason). The problem is that the error log (posted below) won't go away. I'v even tried something as broad as `catch (Exception e)`in order to catch any possible exception, but the crashlog won't go away. Any Advice would be appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks to @jdigital, I discovered that the code **was** in fact catching the exceptions, however that was masked by Selenium outputting it's own exceptions. Any advice on how to have selenium stop outputting errors would be appreciated!

```
 Jan 27, 2014 6:48:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.selector: a[href*='score'])
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: '[Edited out for Privacy]', ip: '[Edited out for Privacy]', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:396)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:432)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:730)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:728)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at Web.WebCrawler.checkIfLoggedIn(WebCrawler.java:89)
    at Web.WebCrawler.access$0(WebCrawler.java:86)
    at Web.WebCrawler$1.run(WebCrawler.java:80)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:298)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:366)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: How about catching `UnreachableBrowserException`?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Same error log.

Comment: How about `ConnectException`?

Comment: To debug, catch `RuntimeException` and you should be able to see the actual exception.  Then add a `catch` for that (and remove the more general RuntimeException).

Comment: No Change - I still get exactly the same error log. I'm adjusting the inner `catch`, so I have no Idea why none of these are being caught.

Comment: Try catching `Throwable`.  Also, have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: By the way, catching exceptions doesn't necessarily prevent the error output from being generated.  A lower level handler could catch the error, print it, and then propagate the exception.

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding  `System.out.println("ERROR CAUGHT")` to the `catch` block, and sure enough it has been catching the error the whole time. I guess my new question is: how do I stop selenium from outputting this error?

Comment: Please update your question with comment above. Without reading comments below, I was trying to reproduce the issue in your question and sure enough I could not because of obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set [Selenium's Logging Preferences](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/logging/LoggingPreferences.html) to customize the exception output.

EDIT: 
Perhaps the instructions at the above referenced link aren't too helpful.
It looks like Selenium uses the standard Java logger interface.  Get hold of the [RemoteWebDriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html) object and then turn off its logging via `setLogLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF)`.

For another alternative, the [FirefoxDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver) allows stdout/stderr to be redirected to a file.  This has the advantage of allowing you to inspect the output should you need to do so; otherwise, you can just overwrite it or delete it.

Comment: I'm Having trouble with Logging Preferences. I tried `LoggingPreferences noLogs = new LoggingPreferences();
  noLogs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.OFF);`

But the logs still appeared. Am I doing something wrong?